# Why is the length of URL-Strings in Magento so different?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I try to find out, if the current url of an user, is the base url of magento. 
so i need this 2 functions:

```
Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()
```

for the current url and:

```
Mage::getUrl('',array('_secure'=>true))
```

for the base url include https.

if i do a `var_dump()` with the first function it returns:

```
string(42) "https://www.example.de/folder/index.php/"
```

and the second:

```
string(51) "https://www.example.de/folder/index.php/"
```

you see, the strings are identical, but the string counter is not.
Could you explain why, and how could i find out, is the users current site is the base url or default home/mainpage.

Answer (score 0):

okay i found this code:

`<?php 
    // IF WE ARE ON HOMEPAGE
    if(
        Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  &&
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'
    ) : ?>
    // Put your homepage-only code in here.
<?php endif; ?>`

on http://www.philowen.co/blog/check-homepage-php-magento/

that's my solution now, but i still cant't explain the different sizes.